# XCODE 4.2.3 to 4.5.2 migration

Tags: xcode

I had developed the application in 4.2.3 that was running fine on simulator after that i migrated my Xcode to 4.5.2.

When i am running app on iphone simulator 6 its running fine,while running on device an error occur "Could not launch application No such file or directory app.app/application_name".

Meanwhile i created a new project and run directly on device its running fine.

its mean is that i have to setting old file?

can any body help me?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

Disconnect your device.

Delete the app from your device.

Quit xcode (Don't just simply close the window, quit it)

Delete derived data folder (~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/-
gbrvhlvwmpiobxdujegtghggrffp - or something like that)

Now start Xcode, connect device and run the project. It should work fine.

There it is.

Comment: Tried all steps but still same "could not launch no such file or directory"

Comment: Sorry about that, I have no ideas then ... :(